# iOS App Facebook Login Screen with Logo

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written an app that uses Facebook login via the `FBSDKLoginButton`.  The login window shows up and the user can login using their Facebook email and passowrd... that all works great!

I am trying to figure out how to make the login window show our company logo but I cannot find this anywhere in the documentation.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have seen many other iOS Apps that use FB Login and have their logo displayed so I know it can be done.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: login screen with the default app icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **change the app icon** of your Facebook app in order to do that.

1. Navigate to developers.facebook.com.
2. Click on **My Apps** on the top right corner.

   [image: My Apps on Facebook for Developers]
3. Select your app.
4. Select **Settings/Basic** from the menu on the left.

   [image: Settings/Basic]
5. Hover over the section called **App Icon** (which is on the bottom left of the first editable section) and click on the **Edit** button.

   [image: App Icon section]